# Graphviz Dot placing node inside subgraph even though it was defined elsewhere

Tags: dot, digraphs

I am trying to make a dot script generator for a homework problem, it's going well except I have this issue where some nodes that are not defined in subgraphs are being placed in them. For example the following dot script:

```
digraph dg {
    compound=true;
    labelloc="t";
    label="test.cpp";
    Vehicle;
    Make;
    subgraph clusterFord {
        label="Ford"
        Ford[shape="none"][style="invis"][label=""];
        Mustang -> Vehicle [label="private"];
        Thunderbird -> Vehicle [label="private"];
    }
    Ford -> Make [label="public"][ltail ="clusterFord"];
    subgraph clusterChevrolet {
        label="Chevrolet"
        Chevrolet[shape="none"][style="invis"][label=""];
        Camero -> Vehicle [label="private"];
    }
    Chevrolet -> Make [label="public"][ltail ="clusterChevrolet"];
}
```

Generates this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU6ib.jpg): 
[image]

The "Vehicle" node is supposed to be outside of the "Ford" subrgraph. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This will give what you want:

```
digraph dg {
    compound=true;
    labelloc="t";
    label="test.cpp";
    subgraph clusterFord {
        label="Ford"
        Ford[shape="none"][style="invis"][label=""];
        Mustang
        Thunderbird
    }
    subgraph clusterChevrolet {
        label="Chevrolet"
        Chevrolet[shape="none"][style="invis"][label=""];
        Camero
    }
    Ford -> Make [label="public"][ltail ="clusterFord"];
    Chevrolet -> Make [label="public"][ltail ="clusterChevrolet"];
    Mustang -> Vehicle [label="private"];
    Thunderbird -> Vehicle [label="private"];
    Camero -> Vehicle [label="private"];
}
```

Comment: In other words, it looks like the location (in source code) where an edge is specified can change the position (in/out of subgraph) of the nodes. Solution: write the edge outside of any subgraph.